# How to test if link on page works

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http

I am trying to write a script that will test if all the anchor tags on a page are working. Essentially, I just want to make sure that the link is not broken. I thought that the best way to do this would be to loop through all of the anchor tags on a page and send an http request to that URL. See code below:

```
function testClicks() {

    for (var i = 0, allLinks = document.links.length; i < allLinks; i++) {
        var thisLink = document.links[i].href,
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('GET', thisLink, false);
        http.send();
        var resonse = http.status;
        console.log(response);
    }

};
```

Right now I am just testing basic links like Google and Yahoo. Right now this is the error I am getting.

```
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://www.google.com/'.
```

I am thinking that I should not be using the GET method. Any insight on this issue could help. Vanilla Javascript only please! No jQuery.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

google.com.ua doesn't allow make cross-origin requests, so that's why you get error. Try to make request to other domains. And yes, cross-origin must be enabled on them. This variant only for AJAX-requests.

I propose make something like ping in javascript. Working example you can find here - http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

The main idea of example above - using images and their callback `onload` for detect if this domain is available.

P.S. I realize this AJAX-requests helper for me (can be helpful):

```
ajax: function(url, cb, data, method) {
        url = url ? url : '';
        cb = typeof cb == 'function' ? cb : function() {};
        data = data ? data : {};
        method = method ? method : 'GET';

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open(method, url, true);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                cb.call(this, this.responseText);
            } else {
                cb.call(this);
            }
        };
        request.onerror = function() {
            cb.call(this);
        };
        request.send(this.getQueryUrl(data)); // You can pass just `null` to send

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: What would be an example of the parameter "cb?" I understand it is short for callback, but I am trying to figure out how it works with the call() method.

Comment: The call() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually. So you can change context of ```this``` in cb method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Being trying to resolve getting a 404 when sending a user to download a file that is no longer there, spent days trying to figure out the best solution for this. This was the best solution I could find for that use case, thank you. @EugeneObrezkov

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will complain if you try to load a resource with `XMLHttpRequest` from a server that doesn't support CORS.

A possible work around is to pretend that the resource is an `Image` instead.

**EDIT** tried that, it didn't work (in Chrome) - downloading an HTML page into an `<img>` element caused the `error` event to fire instead of the `load` event and I can't see any way to differentiate that from the `error` event that's fired if the URL doesn't even exist :(

Comment: ok that makes sense. I can check if the anchor has a link, but how would I check if the link is valid?

Comment: Try and set `Image.src` to the URL, I guess.  What I'm unsure is whether a "broken" image (not a broken link, a link that isn't really an image) would cause the `load` or the `error` event to fire...

Comment: I will give this a test and let you know if it works.

Comment: Yeap, @Alnitak is right. The same idea uses in example, which I had provide in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also work directly with the exception thrown, using a `try...catch` block:

```
try {
    http.send();
    var resonse = http.status;
    console.log(response);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // Do a fallback, call a failure callback, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to call your own local PHP file that uses cURL to check the links. I use this method myself with an array of all the websites that I currently manage (plus a few control URLs like Google) and it works great locally. Remotely, results may vary... I think certain hosts might not like certain other hosts, but I have yet to test that theory.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

You can build it in whatever manner fits your needs, here is an explanation of how mine works.

1. Build a javascript array of all URLs to test if the links are valid (working sites or down sites or broken links)
2. Make an AJAX call for each item in the array to my PHP file ($_GET['url'])
3. PHP file uses cURL to get the headers of the URL to be checked and returns the result in the format I like
4. The results are processed, in my case I output the results into a list/structure and color code each result according to the HTTP response code.

If you are putting this code on a live site you may get varying results according to your host (I did). For my own purposes of checking that my own sites are up and running I use this code locally with XAMPP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use PHP. It has to be an entirely front end solution. No backend available.

Comment: OH, well I'll leave this here for anyone else in the future then. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin requests are not allowed on JavaScript... I had a similar problem... A code worked in Java but not in JavaScript. Both the JavaScript and server side script must be on the same server so you cannot do stuff like send request to google...