# Test a status of a page with Query string with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Basically I have this really simple javascript that gets the ?user=example query string and if it is not found in the list it does nothing but if it is then it redirects to the according profile.

```js
<script>
 var url = window.location.toString();
       var query_string = url.split("?");
               if (query_string[1] === 'user=example') {
       document.location = "https://streety.org/users/example";
               }
</script>
```

Since I have more than one user it would be counterintuitive to put a bunch of if statements for every use so
I want to make it so instead it gets the data and puts it into the url https://streety.org/users/ and then tests if the server returns 404 or 200, if 404 then do  nothing if 200 then redirect user to that page

How could I do test for a valid page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if link on page works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066712/how-to-test-if-link-on-page-works)

Comment: I need regular javascript 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score -1):

This should get you close to what you want.

```js
// Get the URL
const urlQuery = window.location.search;
// use URLSearchParams JS Class to get the query parameters
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(urlQuery);
// If urlParams contains the "user" parameter
if (urlParams.has('user')) {
  // get the value for the user parameter
  let user = urlParams.get('user');
  // Fetch the URL
  fetch('https://streety.org/users/' + user)
    // check the promise
    .then(response => {
    // if the response is OK (between 200-299 response code)
    if (response.ok) {
      // redirect
      document.location = 'https://streety.org/users/' + user;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `is_valid` will always be `false` at that `if` statement because fetch is async/returns a promise

Comment: I just realized you are correct! I'm working on a fix for the answer.

Comment: Thanks to @Samathingamajig I updated the answer (based on my basic knowledge of promises) removing the test variable since we can use a promise for that.

Comment: @Sharkii awesome! Can you please upvote it and mark it as accepted? The down vote will make people think that it doesn't answer the question.